# python proper way to decode raw udp packet

Tags: python, decode, packet

I'm making a script to get Valve's server information (players online, map, etc)
the packet I get when I request for information is this:

```
'\xff\xff\xff\xffI\x11Stargate Central CAP SBEP\x00sb_wuwgalaxy_fix\x00garrysmod\x00Spacebuild\x00\xa0\x0f\n\x0c\x00dw\x00\x0114.09.08\x00\xb1\x87i\x06\xb4g\x17.\x15@\x01gm:spacebuild3\x00\xa0\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

This may help you to see what I'm trying to do https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2S_INFO

The problem is, I don't know how to decode this properly, it's easy to get the string but I have no idea how to get other types like byte and short
for example `'\xa0\x0f'`

For now I'm doing multiple split but do you know if there is any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has functions for encoding/decoding different data types into bytes. Take a look at the `struct` package, the functions `struct.pack()` and `struct.unpack()` are your friends there.

taken from https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
>>> unpack('hhl', '\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
(1, 2, 3)
```

The first argument of the `unpack` function defines the format of the data stored in the second argument. Now you need to translate the description given by valve to a format string. If you wanted to unpack 2 bytes and a short from a data string (that would have a length of 4 bytes, of course), you could do something like this:

```
(first_byte, second_byte, the_short) = unpack("cc!h", data)
```

You'll have to take care yourself, to get the correct part of the data string (and I don't know if those numbers are signed or not, be sure to take care of that, too).

The strings you'll have to do differently (they are null-terminated here, so start were you know a string starts and read to the first `"\0"` byte).

`pack()` work's the other way around and stores data in a byte string. Take a look at the examples on the python doc and play around with it a bit to get a feel for it (when a tuple is returned/needed, e.g.).

`struct` supports you in getting the right byte order, which most of the time is network byte order and different from your system. That is of course only necessary for multi byte integers (like short) - so a format string of `"!h" should unpack a short correctly.

Comment: I tried struct.unpack('xxsssshxxxxxxx',raw) but it didn't worked, do you know what arguement I should write? I don't see the difference between p and s

Comment: @mou I tried to explain the format string a bit. The python docs give you all the details there.

Comment: I tried to pack a string but it didn't worked struct.pack('cs','T',"Source Engine Query.")
'TS' I tried with p and P aswell

Comment: @mou don't use `pack` for your strings. That does not fit with valves description (they use 0-termination. just add them by doing something like `data = data + my_string + "\0"`). `s` and `p` work with strings differently, `P` does not work on strings at all and `S` is not a valid format character. Look at the bytes in the example given by valve where they pack the string to understand what the bytes mean. The String starts at the 53 (="S") and ends at 79 (="y"), terminated by 00. (They actually made an error there, and forgot the 2E (=".")).

Comment: how to unpack a string without knowing its size?

Comment: Just read bytes until you find a 0 byte. Drop that byte, string done. O.c. those strings can never contain 0 bytes, but that's not so bad.